# Rebuild list of containers without scrolling the list

Tags: codenameone

My app shows long lists of containers and when the user edits the content one of them, the whole list must be refreshed since the content in the other containers may change (they may also change size).

Currently I do this simply by  `getContentPane().removeAll()`, followed by recalculating all the containers, and then `revalidate()` to show the updated form. However, when I do this the list scrolls back to the top.

How can I keep the same scroll position in the list, eg that the new instance of the just edited container stays in the same place on the screen as before? I know `scrollComponentToVisible(Component)` but as far as I can see it doesn't allow me to place a container in exactly the same spot on the screen as before the refresh.

Comment: Please add a full code example

Answer (score 0):

Since you rebuilt the position might change so calling `setScrollY()` directly probably won't provide the same position I don't think that's doable since you need functionality that's closer to `scrollComponentToVisible`.

Comment: I looked at the code for `scrollComponentToVisible(Component c)` but not so obvious for me to modify due to the complexity and edge cases covered. Wouldn't it be possible for you to add a `y`parameter to it, to indicate the specific desired y position of the upper edge of `c` after the scroll? Then it would appear to the user as if `c` stays fixed on the screen while the surrounding containers are updated.

Comment: Just noticed another detail. It would also need to avoid the visual scrolling that `scrollComponentToVisible` does, even when the `c` component is already visible at the bottom of the screen where `scrollComponentToVisible` will normally place it.

Comment: You can use `setScrollY()` if you want a specific area as long as you derive `Container`.  You can still call `scrollComponentToVisible` since it won't do anything if the component is fully visible. To disable the animation just call `setSmoothScrolling(false)` but don't forget to return it to true afterwards.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: I should use `setScrollY()` on the container with the list of elements I want to scroll, and the Y value should by the new Y position of the element I want to scroll to the same position as before? Also thanks for the info on `setSmoothScrolling`.

Comment: I was thinking about calling `setScrollY()` to the original `getScrollY()` value from before the remove. This way it will seem like nothing has changed.

Comment: `Container.setScrollY()´ is ´protected´, so I cannot access it from my code. Can you change that?

Comment: Not without breaking user code. You can subclass the `Container` and then have access to that.