# Follow up on: Rebuild list of containers without scrolling the list

Tags: codenameone

Referring to this question and answer by Shai Almog:
[Rebuild list of containers without scrolling the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675988/rebuild-list-of-containers-without-scrolling-the-list#comment66730337_39677122)

I have a form with one container (TableLayout), which contains several rows with labels and buttons. Clicking a button changes the order of the rows and rebuilds the whole form (after `myForm.removeAll()` ). After `myForm.revalidate()` the form jumps to the top.

I am trying to implement this exact behaviour, to return to the same point (scroll position Y) after revalidating/changing the container contents.

I subclassed the Container-class to make `setScrollY(int)` visible. Using this with an arbitrary value does not scroll to the position, so it seems that the `setScrollY` method is not changing the scroll position of the content pane overall.

And `myContainer.getScrollY()` always returns "0". I only get the scroll position by calling `getContentPane().getScrollY()`.

But it is obviously not possible to call the `setScrollY()`-method on the content pane - as it is not possible to subclass the content pane - to scroll back to the same position after revalidating the form.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use border layout which disables the scrolling of the form/content pane.

Place your container (where you exposed `setScroll`) in the center and make sure to invoke `setScrollableY(true)` on that `Container`.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot @Shai to point me to this obviously right solution and this nice way of supporting your cn1-users!! I wish I'd thought about trying BorderLayout for the form.